# SQL server 2005 instance not found

Tags: sql-server-2005, instance

I was using SQL server 2005 express edition and, therefore was limited by a data base 4 giga size. I decided to install SQL server 2005 developper (64bits) in order to be able to go beyond 4 gigabytes data base size.
The installation program  run with no error message on a Windows 7 64 bits, but did not install the SQL server Management Studio. After a couple of investigations, I found out and run the installation program on CD2 SqlRun_Tools.msi which installed the missing tools. I then installed the SQL server SP3 package.
When I opened the Management Studio, the 3 instances of SQL 2005 Express where there but no SQL 2005 developer edition (new) instance was shown.
I restored the system, then removed each one of the SQL server Express instances, then fully reinstalled the SQL 2005 developper edition with its default instance name, but again no SQLserver 2005 Developper instance was listed on the SQL Server management studio. Surprise! the 3 instances from SQL 2005 Express edition (which were all previously uninstalled) were still there, but not accessible.
I have tried to access the new SQL server Developper through my code but the instance has not been found either.
All connection strings have been working for a long time with SQL Express edition and are correct.
I have also checked that SQl server and SQl browser were started.

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you looked in your Services list to ensure that both A)SQL Server Developer is installed and B)The default instance of SQL Server Developer is running?

Comment: BTW, this belongs on SuperUser.com, not this site.